# monitor combobox for change vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

How can I monitor a ComboBox for changes?

The SelectedIndexChanged event only firnges when selection is changed by choosing a different value from the combobox, I would like to monitor chaes when the selection is manually deleted and no value was chosen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about Combobox1.mouseclick?

Answer (score 2):

Easy, simply use the event `TextChanged`:

> Occurs when the Text property value changes.

See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms158340.aspx) about it.

Comment: (A very old answer but gonna comment anyway) Please be reminded that `TextChanged` event will not trigger if the `ComboBox.DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDownList`.

Comment: @CrushSundae Yes it will. That event got fired everytime the Text property of the ComboBox changes

Comment: It didn't work for me. Had to settle with `SelectedValueChanged`. What could possibly be the reason?

Comment: @CrushSundae It works for me. You could create a question so you can provide more data so we can be able to help you with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend combobox class and override SelectedIndexChange event to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can select to `Indexchange or Valuechange or Textchange`

Then, you can try to put some code. Like record it for every change.

like adding below code to the `Valuechange`

```
listbox1.items.add = combobox1.selecteditem
```

Of course you must made the visible to false